A strange movie about "Paint It Black"
I am trying to find a strange movie. As I remember, the key details are:

The narrative established on "Paint It Black" motto,
But I don't remember any The Rolling Stones reference,
It was a black and white movie,
Looks like 60s and 70s,
There were street posters (like "Missing" posters) that calling everyone to paint themselves black
There was a very long improvized scene that captured a group of people in a room who painting theirselves black color with a very delirious way,
And half of the scene was continued with no light,
There were hippies I think,

Do you recognize this movie?
